# Rename files with batch script if exist without overwriting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, overwrite

I am moving files into a new map with a same name. Problem happens when names are the same and it overwrites. If possible I would like to add 01, 02, 03.. at the end of the file or append date. But I gotta keep extensions as they are.

So i wanna change 123.pdf to 123_date.pdf or 12301.pdf and not 123.pdf01. So far I have the first part which overwrites files:

```
@echo off
pushd G:\Purchase
for %%a in (*.*) do (
    md "%%~na" 2>nul
    move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
popd
```

and I have: `set myTimeStamp = _%date:~12,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%`

Comment: In what situation will you overwrite files? You only seem to iterate through the root of the `G:\Purchase` folder. All the source files that you process will have different names because there can't be two files with the same name in one folder.

Comment: Besides the fact that `myTimeStamp` is never set as you have _spaces_ in front of and behind the `=`, what do you need this value for? it is not mentioned elsewhere in the question... Anyway, `%%~xa` holds the pure extension (`.pdf`). And note if a file has no extension, the directory cannot be created...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command [ren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) with an if exist loop